# `gem install <package>` 404 Not Found, Error: Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm having a difficulty with `RubyGem`.

## Environment

1. Windows 64-bit
2. Using Git-Bash in VSCode
3. Ruby 3.2.0 + devkit installed from rubyinstaller.org

## Problem

1. run `gem install bundler` provides this error message:

```
$ gem install bundler -V
HEAD https://index.rubygems.org/
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/Kim/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0
404 Not Found
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    bad response Not Found 404 (https://index.rubygems.org/info/Kim/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0)
        C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:232:in `fetch_http'
        C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:248:in `fetch_path'
        C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver/api_set.rb:105:in `versions'
        C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver/api_set.rb:56:in `find_all'
        C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver/composed_set.rb:54:in `block in find_all'
        C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver/composed_set.rb:53:in `map'
        C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver/composed_set.rb:53:in `find_all'
        C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver/best_set.rb:30:in `find_all'
        C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver/installer_set.rb:170:in `find_all'
        C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver/installer_set.rb:61:in `add_always_install'
        C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:322:in `resolve_dependencies'
        C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:201:in `install_gem'
        C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:226:in `block in install_gems'
        C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:219:in `each'
        C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:219:in `install_gems'
        C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:167:in `execute'
        C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/command.rb:323:in `invoke_with_build_args'
        C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:185:in `process_args'
        C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:149:in `run'
        C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:51:in `run'
        C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

2. run `gem env` provides this error message:

```
$ gem env
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown environment option [Kim/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0]
        C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/commands/environment_command.rb:93:in `execute'
        C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/command.rb:323:in `invoke_with_build_args'
        C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:185:in `process_args'
        C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:149:in `run'
        C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:51:in `run'
```

What could be the cause of this problem?
What steps can I follow to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: This might mean that it can't find the bundler with that version.

What's your default Ruby version? You mentioned 3.2.0, but I see in the error message 3.1.0. So maybe it didn't install correctly and it can't find it.
check `ruby -v`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines indicate that your shell environment is misconfigured:

```
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/Kim/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0
404 Not Found
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    bad response Not Found 404 (https://index.rubygems.org/info/Kim/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0)
```

You should instead see this:

```
HEAD https://index.rubygems.org/
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/bundler
200 OK
```

This line also indicates a misconfiguration:

```
Unknown environment option [Kim/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0]
```

This is most likely caused by the `gemrc` or `.gemrc` file having incorrect contents. The location of this file on Windows varies so I would recommend looking in the following locations for it:

1. `%USERPROFILE%` (typically `C:\Users\<your username>`
2. `C:\ProgramData`
3. `C:\Ruby31-x64`

If you can't find the file in any of those locations then perform a search of `C:\` to find it.

Once you've found it you can either edit the file to remove the invalid values or you can delete it entirely. (or more preferably, rename it so that you can restore it if necessary)

Comment: Hello, is it `gemrc` or `.gemrc`?

Comment: @Hitit On macOS and Linux it's `.gemrc`. On Windows it is possibly `gemrc` because Windows doesn't allow filenames to start with a period, but this depends on a few different factors. Look for both filenames.

Comment: I confirmed that it's `gemrc` on windows under `C:\Users\<your username>`. 

Changing gemrc name (technically removing it) solved my problem. Thank you for your help!